# HTTP to HTTPS rewrite and pass request to $1.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I can't get this to work.

Before I had HTTPS, I had:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php`

Simple. Request for `/page/` became `/page.php`

I added HTTPS:

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

That works. But I can't get the  `/page/` to `/page.php` behavior to work anymore with any of the rules I try to create:

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.php`

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php`

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1.php`

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1.php`

`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1.php`

I don't know what to do to get the HTTP rewrite to work on HTTPS...

EDIT:
`.htaccess`

`DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1.php
    </IfModule>`

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess and also clarify what you mean by `That works. But I can't get the .php file to load anymmore`?

Comment: Added to post, thanks.
"But I can't get the /page/ to /page.php behavior to work anymore with any of the rules I try to create:"

Comment: Is this a WordPress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using 2 different rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# add .php internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```